# How use $ in Markdown?

Tags: markdown, google-colaboratory

[image]

I'm trying to use **$** twice in a row in a sentence. However in the output it returns a bold italicized phrase between the **$**

How could I type $ twice without this function appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` indicates the beginning and end of a mathematical formula in which characters are italic by default. Replace `$` with `\$` to show just the dollar sign.